# How to copy with statement result to local in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, common-table-expression, postgresql-copy

I have following with statement and copy command

```
with output01 as
(select * from (
select name,
case
    when column1 is not null and lower(column1) in ('point1','point2','point3','point4') then 3456
    else null end column1Desc,
case
    when column2 is not null and lower(column2) in ('point1','point2','point3','point4') then 2456
    else null end column2Desc,
column3, column4),
output02 as
(select * from (
select name,
case
    when column1 is not null and lower(column1) in ('point1','point2','point3','point4') then 3456
    else null end column1Desc,
case
    when column2 is not null and lower(column2) in ('point1','point2','point3','point4') then 2456
    else null end column2Desc,
column3, column4),
output3 as (SELECT * FROM output01 UNION ALL SELECT * FROM output02)

\copy (select * from output3) to '/usr/share/output.csv' with CSV ENCODING 'UTF-8' DELIMITER ',' HEADER;
```

I am getting following ERROR

> ERROR:  relation "tab3" does not exist

Comment: Your query is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All `psql` backslash commands need to be written on a single line, so you can't have a multi-line query together with `\copy`. The only workaround is to create a (temporary) view with that query, then use that in the `\copy` command.

Something along the lines:

```
create temporary view data_to_export
as
with cte as (..)
select * 
from cte
;

\copy (select * data_to_export) to ...
```

Comment: You need a "()" around your full "with cte...select * from cte;" statement

Comment: @KevinJonaitis: parentheses around the query of a view are unnecessary and completely useless: https://dbfiddle.uk/5vGI9wdh

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because you are running your `CTE` query and `copy` command in different statements. Considering your `with` query is working fine, you should write your `copy` statement like below:

```
\copy (WITH tab1 as (Your SQL statement),
tab2 as ( SELECT ... FROM tab1 WHERE your filter),
tab3 as ( SELECT ... FROM tab2 WHERE your filter)
SELECT * FROM tab3) to '/usr/share/results.csv' with CSV ENCODING 'UTF-8' DELIMITER ',' HEADER;
```

Comment: tried this but getting ERROR:  syntax error at or near ","

Comment: updated my actual query format it contains many cases so with your solution, query fails on first with clause

Comment: @swan The query you have mentioned in all 3 `with` is incomplete. Please have a look at it. Please first run your query directly and check whether you are getting the output or not. Once it will run correctly then append it in the `()` of copy. It will work definitely.

Comment: after executing whole query it works perfectly fine on pgAdmin Querytool but on command prompt it did not work

Comment: All `psql` backslash commands need to be written on a single line, so you can't have a multi-line query together with `\copy`

Comment: whole query is of 1500 lines so it works on querytool

Comment: @horse yes i thinks its due to long lines and multiple line...some character making problem